# How to find Informix Client SDK for Ubuntu

Tags: php, pdo, informix

I am a beginner on Informix database and I need to connect to Informix databases using PHP code.
I succeeded to download `php_pdo_informix` tar file but during installation, it requires Informix Client SDK includes by sending this error line :

> checking for includes and libraries... configure:
>   error: Cannot find Informix Client SDK includes in /opt/informix/inc/cli"

then I am not able to find the right place to download this Informix Client SDK in other to proceed with the configuration

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get it from IBM — but finding where to go can be hard work.  A good starting point would be the International Informix User Group ([IIUG](http://www.iiug.org/)) web site, and in particular the ['free database download'](http://www.iiug.org/en/2016/10/27/free-informix-database-engines/) page, which leads to a relevant section of the IBM site.  Downloading the database server product includes the ClientSDK (aka CSDK).  You can install just the CSDK, AFAIK.  You do have to register at the IBM site to do the download.

You may find the [Informix Client SDK System Requirements](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016673) page useful.

I did a general search for ['download informix csdk'](https://www.ibm.com/Search/?q=download+informix+csdk) and it came up with some useful places, but the IIUG lead was quicker.

Comment: hi, thanks for this useful orientation, i succeeded to download the iif.12.10.UC5DE.Linux-RHEL5.tar file but during installation, i am getting this error message : 
**./ids_install: 3345: exec: /tmp/install.dir.14421/Linux/resource/jre/jre/bin/java: not found**

i guess there is something missing and i dont know what

Comment: the JRE is included in the installation. Is your machine capable of running a 32-bit process? The IDS version you downloaded is a 32-bit one. (the 'U' in the suffix 'UC5DE' correspond with 32-bit. for 64-bit you want an 'F' like 'FC5DE'.

Comment: i solved this by installing the **libc6-i386**  and **libgcc1:i386**  now i am facing issue related to missing license files 

Missing license file LA_in
Missing license file LI_in
"

Comment: i also resolve above issue by downloading instead the **iif.12.10.FC9DE.linux-x86_64.tar** file and installation was successful 
thanks for your help !!!

Comment: Good — glad you're at least on to the next hurdle.  Good luck.  May all the future hurdles be small enough not to trip you up.